# How do i get to this step in the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I read a book with this equation in it:

$x = (P + 1)(1 - y)$
$1-y=x(1/(P+ 1))$

I fail to understand how it works. When I try I get:
$1-y = x/(P+1)$

What am I missing?

Comment: It's the same thing:$$x(1/(P+1))=x\frac{1}{P+1}=\frac{x\cdot1}{P+1}=\frac{x}{P+1}=x/(P+1)\ .$$

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may just look confusing because it's written "in line", so to speak, with slashes for division, perhaps clouding what it's actually stating. Writing it in fractional form, we see the product of $x$ and $1/(P+1)$ is none other than $x$ divided by $P+1$:$$x\cdot \left(\frac{1}{P+1}\right) = \frac x{P+1}$$

Comment: You are right, that makes it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Jimmy!